# how to hide on item in a class if the following element is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML as follows and want to hide the item with the class `roles` if the following `div` is empty.

```
<b class="roles">heading 1</b>
<div>...</div>

<b class="roles">heading 2</b>
<div></div>
```

In this instance the first heading should show though the second would be hidden. The jQuery I have tried is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.roles').next().is(':empty').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Here is my CSS regarding the `hidden` class:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You missed `.` of class `hidden` in CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over all the `.roles` elements to check if that individual instance has an empty div following it. Try this:

```js
$('.roles').each(function() {
  if ($(this).next('div').is(':empty'))
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b class="roles">heading 1</b>
<div>Not empty</div>
<b class="roles">heading 2</b>
<div></div>
```

Comment: ah perfect, I was thinking of some for loop but couldn't figure out how to get it to work, thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 3):

For multiple `.roles` you've to loop over each of the element and check the condition for each element.

```
$('.roles').each(function() {
    if ($(this).next().is(':empty')) {
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the opposite logic:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div:empty').prev('.roles').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Or using following selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.roles + div:empty').prev().addClass('hidden');
});
```